# Passbook notification failing

Tags: ios6, passbook

Followed the intermediate Passbook tutorial from the book "iOS 6 by tutorials"
http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-6-by-tutorials

I'm able to send a pass by email, add it to pass book, update it in my app and it updates when I open passbook but I'm not getting any notification. Notifications are turned on in the settings.

My guess is that it could be the firewall of my server. I'm new to the howl server setup. I'm running on a godaddy vps (centos).
When I run a list on iptables I get the following:

iptables -L -vn

[image]

Does this look right ?
Any clue appreciated !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely due to a firewall issue on the server side - but could possibly be an issue with the firewall of the router that your device is connected to.  Apple delivers push notifications to devices on port 5223, so this needs to be open on your local router (assuming you are connected by wifi).  If you can receive push notifications from other Apps (WhatsApp, Facebook, etc.) then you can rule out firewall as an issue.

You state that the pass does get updated - this implies that either a push is being received by Apple and is triggering the device to retrieve the new pass from your web service, or if you are using `replacePassWithPass` to update the pass via an App, this is functioning as expected.

In order for the pass to display a notification message:

- A pass data field must have changed (changing pass types, colours, images or label values will not trigger a notification), and
- The field must have the `changeMessage` key set (ideally the `changeMessage` contains `%@` which will be replaced by the new field value)

If the above two criteria are met and you are still not receiving a notification, then try hooking your device up to Xcode and watching the console log as you update a pass.

Comment: I'm receiving notifications from other apps, and checked again notification is on for passbook. What's odd is that I'm really only missing the badge as if I update the pass and wait 30 minutes before I open passbook, the pass in passbook will say "updated 30 minutes ago". An output of my console with detail on actions taken is available here:https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12869820/console%20output.txt

Comment: Your console output looks as expected - I suspect it is the `changeMessage` in the pass.  Any chance you can post the before and after .pkpass bundles?  If the field value is changing and a `changeMessage` value is set then there is no reason why it should not notify and you may need to file a bug with Apple.  In your case, your App triggers the update, which should trigger Passbook to display the notification - there's no push messaging involved.